# Function that can count how many numbers in array A fall in the range from low to high.

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm completing a problem set for an introductory computer science class and I'm a bit confused as to what I'm supposed to be doing with this program. The question is: In one file there is a list of of scores for some participants in an athletic competition. The list is organized in the order in which the participants registered for the competition, not in order of score. A separate file contains a set of ranges. Your job is to write a program that can read the data in these two files and print a table showing how many of the participants fell into each of the given ranges.

The question is copied word for word, but I have a few questions about this question. if you could leave a comment stating your opinion about the following, that would be nice:

1) Okay, so I've written some code in order to  read the numbers from the first data file, place the numbers in the array A and return a count of the number of numbers read or N, whichever is smaller. Which follows as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readNumbers(FILE* input, int A[], int N)
{       
    int n;
    n = 0;
    while (n < N&&!feof(input))
    {
        fscanf_s(input, "%f", &A[n]);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
int count(const int A[], int N, int low, int high){

}
```

2) My confusion lies in using this second function to count how many numbers in array A fall in the range from low to high, inclusive. The parameter N tells you how many numbers are in the array. And use these two functions to construct and print a table of how many participants are in each of the categories given in the second file.

Now that I try to talk myself through it, I am now even more confused. Maybe I'm just making the question more difficult. Any tips will help. Thanks

Comment: The code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sort the arrays and simply see the number of scores in each range.

Comment: @Pinepara I realize that... Hence me asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > to count how many numbers in array A fall in the range from low to high, inclusive.

   That `count()` could be implemented like this

   ```
   int count(const int A[], int N, int low, int high){
           int i, cnt;

           for (i = cnt = 0; i < N; i++) {
                   if (low <= A[i] && A[i] <= high)
                           cnt++;
           }
           return cnt;
   }
   ```
2. > use these two functions to construct and print a table of how many participants are in each of the categories given in the second file.

   You could achieve this by using a simple loop

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < number_of_categories; i++) {
           printf("%d - %d : %d\n", low[i], high[i],
                           count(A, N, low[i], high[i]));
   }
   ```

   Suppose you already put all those categories information to `low[]` and `high[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the input files are supposed to look like, I guessed one number per line.

Scores file:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
19
29
39
49
59
69
79
89
99
99
99
99
99
99
99
100
```

Ranges File:

```
0
10
11
20
21
30
31
40
41
50
51
60
61
70
71
80
81
90
91
100
```

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readNumbers(FILE* input, int A[], int N)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (n < N && !feof(input))
    {
        fscanf_s(input, "%d", &A[n]);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
int count(const int A[], int N, int low, int high) {
    int i = 0, numbers_in_range = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) numbers_in_range += (A[i] >= low && A[i] <= high) ? 1 : 0;

    return numbers_in_range;
}
inline int exiting(char* reason)
{
    if(reason != 0) printf("%s\n", reason);
    printf("Usage: rangechecker \"scoresfilename\" \"rangesfilename\"\n");
    printf("exiting...\n");
    exit (-1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int* scores = 0;
    int* ranges = 0;

    int num_scores = 0, num_ranges = 0;

    FILE* scoresfptr;
    FILE* rangesfptr;

    switch (argc) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        exiting(0);
        break;
        case 3:
        //verify files exist and open them
        if((scoresfptr = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL || (rangesfptr = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            exiting("One of the files does not exist or cannot be opened.");
        }
    break;
    default:
        exiting(0);
        break;
    }
    //kind of dumb, but because N is a passed value you kinda gotta
    //know N ahead of the call to readnumber or count
    //that, or I am just tired.
    int ch = 0;
    //assuming instructions are correct, a list, 1 number per line
    //will fail if extra newlines in file
    do {
        ch = fgetc(scoresfptr);
        if (ch == '\n')
            num_scores++;
    } while(ch != EOF);
    //now we have N, can call readnumbers.  Put file pointer back at start of file.
    rewind(scoresfptr);
    //Can also now allocate memory for A[].
    scores = (int*)calloc(num_scores, sizeof(int));
    //check return value to see if anything was read in
    if(readNumbers(scoresfptr, scores, num_scores) > 0) {
        //musta been something in the file
        //get the ranges
        ch = 0;
        //assuming instructions are correct, a list, 1 number per line
        do {
            ch = fgetc(rangesfptr);
            if (ch == '\n')
                num_ranges++;
        } while(ch != EOF);
        //now we have N, can call readnumbers.  Put file pointer back at start of file.
        rewind(rangesfptr);
        //Can also now allocate memory for A[].
        ranges = (int*)calloc(num_ranges, sizeof(int));
        //check return value to see if anything was read in
        if(readNumbers(rangesfptr, ranges, num_ranges) > 0) {
            //now we can call count
            //print header column
            printf("ranges\tscores in range\n");
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < num_ranges/2; i++, j += 2)
            {
                printf("%d-%d:\t%d\n",  *(ranges + j),
                                    *(ranges + j + 1),
                                    count(scores, num_scores,   *(ranges + j),
                                                                *(ranges + j + 1)));
            }
        }
        else {
            exiting("Ranges File empty.");
        }
    }
    else {
        exiting("Scores File empty.");
    }
    free(scores);
    free(ranges);
    fclose(scoresfptr);
    fclose(rangesfptr);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
ranges  scores in range
0-10:   11
11-20:  1
21-30:  1
31-40:  1
41-50:  1
51-60:  1
61-70:  1
71-80:  1
81-90:  1
91-100: 8
```